# NetLogo: the use of a patches-own variable gives an error-message

Tags: netlogo

I have a problem with the difference between the turtle/patch context and the observer context. 
The problem arises with the last line of my code. I want a certain amount of patches to do something and this amount is defined by a variable that I define above. When I use ask n-of 5 patches it works fine, but when I replace 5 by the variable it gives an error message (you can't use tick in a turtle/patch context, because TICK is observer-only). 
Does anyone know why it does not work?

```
patches-own [kans-op-ontbossing]


to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [if (random 100) < bosdensiteit [set pcolor green]]
  ask n-of world-height patches with [pxcor = pycor][set pcolor blue]
  ask n-of world-height patches with [pxcor = max-pxcor / 2] [set pcolor grey]
  ask n-of aantal-nederzettingen patches with [pcolor != blue and pcolor != grey] [set pcolor white]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if ticks = 75 [stop]
  ask patches [set kans-op-ontbossing ontbossingsgevoeligheid + houtprijs + vraag-naar-landbouwgrond]
  ontbos
  tick
end

to ontbos
  ask patches with [pcolor = green and (pxcor > 30 or pycor > 30)]
      [if count (neighbors4 with [pcolor = grey]) >= 1 or count (neighbors4 with [pcolor = blue]) >= 1 or count (neighbors with [pcolor = white]) >= 1
      [if random 300 < kans-op-ontbossing [set pcolor brown]]]


  ask n-of (kans-op-ontbossing / 10) patches with [pcolor = grey and pxcor = ((max-pxcor / 2) + ticks)][ask patch-at 1 0 [set pcolor grey]]

end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kans-op-ontbossing` is a `patches-own`variable. So, you're asking NetLogo to ask some number of patches, based on a variable that may differ between all patches. It's the same as saying `ask n-of ( pcolor / 10 ) patches`- it doesn't really make sense in this context. `n-of` needs its argument to be a single numerical value, which is why 5 works. The reason this specific error comes up, as far as I can tell, is because from NetLogo's point of view, you're trying to access a `patches-own` variable and then lead straight into the `tick` call. Replace the `kans-op-ontbossing` with a value that the observer can access and you should be good to go.